# VueJS 2 - Default click event on component

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible in VueJS to have a default click event on a custom component?

E.g. we have built a component called `editable`. Now on click, we always want it to fire the same function, no matter where we call that component.

```
<editable @click="doSomething" ...></editable>
```

Can I define that somewhere in the JS side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of custom component, you need to bind to native event:

```
<editable @click.native="doSomething" ...></editable>
```

For documentation, refer to [Vue.js docs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

Comment: Thanks, that was easy :)